# How to connecting the function, createElement and random?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code and I am trying to make a button that makes random buttons but I cant connect the code right.

```
p id="demo">Click the button to display a random number. /p>

button onclick="myFunction()">Try it     /button>

script type="text/javascript">


    function myFunction(){
        var num = 5;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Math.floor(Math.random()*num)

        var box=document.createElement("BUTTON");
        document.body.appendChild(box);

        var c = num + box;
        return c;
    }
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: what you want its not clear.

Comment: Your current function does output a random number into the `#demo` element, appends an empty `<button>` to the body and returns `"5[object HTMLButtonElement]"`. What is the expected result? "*Make random buttons*" is too vague.

Comment: i have a button and ever time i put it, it will make a random of 5 box but my code only generate a random number and a new box ever time i put it. but iam trying to make random box with the limit of 5

Comment: @Søren: You mean you want to generate a random number of boxes? What do you want to limit, the overall number of boxes?

Comment: yes i want to limit the overall number of boxes and i only want to see  the boxes.

Comment: And what should be random then? The content of the boxes, or the number of boxes added per click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are trying to create '**n' no.of random buttons as of in the `innerHTML` of `#demo`.**

If so you need to loop it.  Try this

```
function myFunction() {
    var num = 5;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * num)
    var noOfButtons = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfButtons; i++) {
        var box = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        document.body.appendChild(box);
    }
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcgFS/1/)

***From your comments:***

1) No display of numbers, so *remove the `innerHTML` of `#demo` element*.

2) Reset the button count for each button invoke.

*Whenever you invoke the click event, better reset the value to empty like below*

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '';
```

3) *You need to append the child (`box`) to the `#demo` element* instead of body like below

```
document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(box);
```

Finally, your code should look like this.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '';
    var num = 5;
    var noOfButtons = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
    console.log(noOfButtons);
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfButtons; i++) {
        var box = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(box);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcgFS/4/)</kbd>

Hope you got some idea.

Comment: I have a button and ever time i put it, it will make a random of 5 box but my code only generate a random number and a new box ever time i put it. but iam trying to make random box with the limit of 5

Comment: @SørenPhithak Is this like http://jsfiddle.net/hcgFS/2/

Comment: Thank for the help now iam closer to want iam trying to do, but how do i remove the number that also show up and how do i reset it so it dont continued ?

Comment: @SørenPhithak you don't want the numbers to be displayed right?  Check this http://jsfiddle.net/hcgFS/3/

Comment: Thanks alot but i have one more question how do i reset it so it dont continued to make the box ever time i put it ?

Comment: @SørenPhithak Oh I missed it  check this http://jsfiddle.net/hcgFS/4/  Hope this is your expectation.

Comment: Thanks alot you are a bro that i can count on :)

Comment: @SørenPhithak I'm glad that I was able to help.  Extended my answer for you understanding :)

Comment: @SørenPhithak If you find my answer useful, you can mark it as right answer.